# I want to show "All" as an option in primeng p-table paginator

Tags: angular, primeng, paginator

I have a primeng p-table, where I have `[rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 20, 30]"`,
I also want to have an option which says 'All' on click of which it should display the entire row available in the table.

I tried this based on paginator component documentation.
`[rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 20, { showAll: All }]"`

but this does not help.
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/paginator

`[rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 20, { showAll: All }]"`

expected: i shall be able to see 'All'

Please provide answer in this stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vmghz6-ytjegc?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way i found is:
[rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 20, records.length]"

```
.ui-paginator .ui-dropdown .ui-dropdown-panel ul li:last-child {
  span::before {
    content: "All";
    visibility: visible;
  }
  span::after {
    content: "";
  }
  span {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You're just missing the quotes around 'All':

`[rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 20, { showAll: 'All' }]"`

Comment: this also gives the same input. Can you edit this stackblitz and check?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vmghz6-ytjegc?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

This is most correct answer resulting in display value of all dropdown items as :ALL,
I had to make some alterations to the styling to fix that.
Here is the final corrected style:

```
.ui-paginator {
  border: 0 none;
  padding: 1em;

  .ui-dropdown {
    float: left;

    .ui-dropdown-panel {
      ul {
        p-dropdownItem:last-child > li {
          &:last-child {
            span::before {
              content: "All";
              visibility: visible;
            }

            span::after {
              content: "";
            }

            span {
              visibility: hidden;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .ui-paginator-current {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me i wanted to make the all at the end and when i looked to the [source control](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/19df5df79629a72490add7d078a8d0e5ce52f41e/src/app/components/paginator/paginator.ts#L157) of primeng they unsheft the all to be on top so had to do it using a custom templete

```
<p-table 
    [value]="products"
    [rows]="productsTable.rows"  
    [paginator]="true"
    [rowsPerPageOptions]="[ 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, products?.length]" 

<ng-template let-item pTemplate="paginatordropdownitem">
      {{ item.value === products?.length ? 'All' : item.value }}
 </ng-template>
```

Comment: This seemed to work for the most part, but once you select it, the dropdown input displays the actual number it represents instead of 'All'

Answer (score 0):

@Anmol Jain answer with recent version of prime ng and component scss.

```
::ng-deep .p-paginator {
  border: 0 none;
  padding: 1em;
  .p-dropdown {
    float: left;
    .p-dropdown-panel {
      ul {
        p-dropdownItem:last-child > li {
          &:last-child {
            span::before {
              content: "All";
              visibility: visible;
            }

            span::after {
              content: "";
            }

            span {
              visibility: hidden;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .p-paginator-current {
    float: right;
  }
}
```